# Proving that no mapping of a set into its power set can be surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm reading this [SEP article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) which begins by proving no mapping $F: X \to \text{pow}(X)$ can be surjective. For this end, the following subset is considered

$$A= \{x \in X | x \notin {F(x)} \}$$

I follow everything in the proof, but one thing isn't clear, how do we know that $A$ is non empty?

Comment: $A$ may be empty.  The goal is to show that $A\not\in\operatorname{Image}(F)$.  If $A=\emptyset$ the conclusion is that $\emptyset\not\in\operatorname{Image}(F)$ which is just as good a proof that $F$ is not surjective as any.

Comment: In fact, if $F(x)=\{x\}$ then $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: You can trace through the proof to see that emptiness or nonemptiness of $A$ is simply never an issue. The important issue is that $A$ is an element of the set $\text{pow}(X)$ but $A$ is not an element of the image of the mapping $F : X \to \text{pow}(X)$.

Answer (score 3):

Whether A is empty or not plays no role in the proof:

Assume that F is surjective. Then since A ∈ pow(X), there must be some a ∈ X such that F(a) = A.

Now consider the only two possibilities: a ∈ A, or else a ∉ A.

If a ∈ A, then by the definition of A, a ∉ F(a) (= A), so: Contradiction.

If a ∉ A, then by the definition of A, a ∈ F(a) (= A), so: Contradiction.

Therefore the assumption that F is surjective leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $ A $ is empty. Then, as we follow the proof, we want to show that $ A $ is not 'in the range of $ F $', meaning there is no $ a \in X $, such that $ F(a) = A $. Let's assume (again) that such an $ a $ exists. That would mean $ F(a) = A = \varnothing $. But that means $ a \not\in F(a) $, hence $ A $ is not empty! Here is a contradiction, so either there is no $ a $, such that $ F(a) = A $, which is exactly what we want to prove here, or $ A $ is not empty — and that case is dealt with in the article.